# How do you find the last modified folder in a directory with command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, xcopy

In the end, I want to copy the last modified folder in a directory. In order to do this, I need to pass in the name of the last modified folder to xcopy.

How do you find the last modified folder, not file, in a directory with command prompt? I have found many scripts that will find the last modified file, but I cannot seem to find a command that will find the last modified folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir /ad /od /b ') do set "folder=%%a"
```

Comment: Thanks foxidrive, that worked great when I got rid of the second % next to the a's.